# How to set a flag inside an array of hash loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have processed an input file and created a data structure of below format

```
final = [ {:server=>"new_US_dof1_new"},
{:name=>"OLAUS51", :data=>{"HAL"=>"6.93817139", "CCN_RESP"=>".035400391", "PA_RESP"=>".032287598", "PE_RESP"=>".000610352"}},
{:name=>"OLAUS10", :data=>{"HAL"=>"52.7266846", "CFG_RESP"=>"15.9489746"}},
{:name=>"IdofQA03", :data=>{"PA_RESP"=>".096374512"}},
{:name=>"QEMDB", :data=>{"HAL"=>"22.2698975", "PA_RESP"=>"11.7857666", "CCN_RESP"=>".229125977", "PE_RESP"=>".007202148"}},
{:name=>"OLAUS64", :data=>{"CCN_RESP"=>".757202148"}},
{:name=>"IISCR70", :data=>{}},
{:name=>"IQDV500", :data=>{}},
{:name=>"OLAUS80", :data=>{"PA_RESP"=>"10.5393066", "HAL"=>"4.73620605", "CCN_RESP"=>".023864746", "PE_RESP"=>".003723145", "OPENREPORTS"=>".001708984", "REPORT_RESP"=>".001281738"}},

{:server=>"new_US_dof2_new"},
{:name=>"IBDVHAL", :data=>{"HAL"=>"1.81048584", "FM_RESP"=>".001098633"}},
{:name=>"DEVSITEP", :data=>{"HAL"=>".088012695", "PE_RESP"=>".000610352"}},
{:name=>"OLAUS87", :data=>{"CFG_RESP"=>"1.57061768", "HAL"=>".47253418", "PA_RESP"=>".011962891", "PE_RESP"=>".007202148"}}]
```

I've come up with below code to process and get the above mentioned format

```
final = []
count = -1

output = File.open("input.txt").read
output.each_line do |line|
  line.strip!
  next if line.empty?
  next if line.include?('rows') || line.include?('occ')
  next if ['-','='].include? line[0]
  parts = line.split ' '
   if parts.size == 1 and line.start_with?('new_')
    final[count += 1] = {server: line, data: {}}
    next
  elsif parts.size == 1 and parts = /^(?!.*new_).*$/
    final[count += 1] = {name: line, data: {}}
    next
  end

  parts.each_cons(2) do |key, value|
    final[count][:data][key] = value 
    end
end

p = Axlsx::Package.new
p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Basic") do |sheet|

    style1 = sheet.styles.add_style(:bg_color => "EF0920", :fg_color => "FFFFFF", b:true, :sz => 14, :alignment => { :horizontal=> :center })
    style2 = sheet.styles.add_style(:bg_color => "00FF00", :fg_color => "FFFFFF", b:true, :sz => 12, :alignment => { :horizontal=> :center })
    sheet.add_row ["VM", "NAME", "DATA", "SIZE"], :style => style1

    final.each do |val|
     if val.key?(:server) 
       sheet.add_row [ val[:server], val[:name], "", "" ] , :style =>[style2, nil]
       next
    elsif val.key?(:name)
      sheet.add_row [ "", val[:name], "", "" ]
      val[:data].each do |k, v|
        sheet << ["", "", k, v]
          end       
       end
    end 
end
```

I'm trying to format the data to below structure (**Expected**)

[image]

but my code throws output like,

[image]

So, I have modified the printing values to

```
val[:data].each do |k, v|
        sheet << [val[:server], val[:name], k, v]
    end
```

but that prints server & name values on every line
[image]

I did a string validation to match lines starting with 'new_' using a if loop  and pushing the server & name values to a new array thereby printing only unique value for every iteration, but nothing worked. Will setting a flag be of any help here ?

i'm not exactly getting a logic how to print the server and name values only once like I've mentioned above. (Expected section)

Also, the tricky thing is to leave a blank row for every 'name' section - like an empty row between OLAUS51 & OLAUS10, likewise for other name values
and between every server values too -new_US_dof1_new & new_US_dof2_new.

Any help to sort out this would be of great help, thanks a ton!!

Comment: Please don't use pictures in your question.  Use only text.

Comment: @tukan : Sure, noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? Based on my past answer:

```
final.each_with_object([]) do |val, line|
  # when key :server exist set server's name as first element for line
  # otherwise set empty value to create a blank cell at position 1
  line << (val.key?(:server) ? val[:server] : '') if line.empty?

  # when key :server exist, in the current hash no needed data
  next if val.key?(:server)

  # at this place line look like [server_name/'']
  # so, when no key :server, in each base hash present keys :name and :data
  line << val[:name]

  # line => [server_name, name] for new server
  # line => ['', name] for new properties for the same server

  # for {name: 'some name', data: {}}
  sheet.add_row [*line, '', ''], :style =>[style2, nil] if val[:data].empty?

  val[:data].each do |k, v|
    # add values from data hash
    line << k << v

    # push line to the sheet
    # first iteration for val[:data]
    # line => [server_name/'', name, data_key, data_value]
    # iteration 2+
    # line => ['', '', data_key, data_value]
    sheet.add_row line.clone, :style =>[style2, nil]

    # array line from each_with_object can't be replaced but can be cleaned
    line.clear

    # line => []
    # push two blank values
    line << '' << ''
    # line => ['', '']
    # that line's data will be used for the current loop
  end

  # add a blank line after block :data
  sheet.add_row []

  # line => ['', '']
  # cleaning a line for next hash
  line.clear
  # line => []
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..  but instead of server value its printing True or false and there is format mismatch. 

`SERVER    NAME        DATA            size 
 TRUE   FALSE        INDQA51        PAL        6.93817139
                 YCC_OWNER    0.035400391 
                 PA_OWNER     0.032287598 
                 PE_OWNER     0.000610352 
    
 FALSE  INDQA10   PAL          52.7266846 
                CFG_OWNER      15.9489746

so on` 

Some has empty values like `{:name=>"IISCR70", :data=>{}}
{:name=>"IQDV500", :data=>{}}` as shown in the question .Any chance due to this ?

Comment: SOrry, I know the format is not proper if required I can send you the final output.

Comment: Really appreciate for all your time here. 
I tried your latest edit, in case of server data the format is getting mismatched.. 
any chance it might have any nil value ? 

`SERVER              NAME      DATA       size 
new_US_dof1_new                INDQA51   PAL 6.93817139
......
......
new_US_dof2_new                IBDVHAL    HAL   1.81048584
......
......
so on..`

Comment: @Goku, can you detect hash that produces the error? Can that be related to `[style2, nil]`?

Comment: I tried removing the [style2, nil]?  but still the format for the server value is not correct

Comment: @Goku, that was my mistake, please try again

Comment: Wow !!! that's perfect, what did I miss :( 

One final glitch - the color or style2 gets applied to all the rows of the SERVER column . I'm just checking whether - style2  can be applied only to the server columns like - `'new_US_dof1_new'` or `'new_US_dof2_new'` so on..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176040/discussion-between-goku-and-leo).